# Dropdown menu using WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, drop-down-menu, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to find on internet how can I using dropdown menu on Windows Phone 8  but I can not find illustrative something. How can I using dropdown menu on WP8.

Thanks in advance.

(sorry my language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/), use the ContextMenu control.

Answer (score 2):

you can fill data as:

```
    <toolkit:ListPicker>
           <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="{Binding LocalizedResources.woman, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
           <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="{Binding LocalizedResources.man, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
           <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="{Binding LocalizedResources.other, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Also you can do this by using binding and data template.

Answer (score 1):

See the `ListPicker` control from the [Windows Phone Toolkit](https://phone.codeplex.com/). You can find samples in there.

Comment: Thanks. Problem has solved. But now I can not fill in the listpicker tabs. So I want to fill data(local string ex: woman/man/other) in listpicker tabs.